# Can I use the phrase "cosmic irony"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

My essay is about the Greek Tragedy "Oedipus the king". I want to use the term cosmic irony in a paraphrase but I am unsure whether or not it would weaken my argument. Since I can not find support for this idea in another credible website.

> **cosmic irony**
>
> Part of Speech:       n
>
> Definition:       *the idea that fate, destiny, or a god controls and
> toys with human hopes and expectations*; also, the belief that the
> universe is so large and man is so small that the universe is
> indifferent to the plight of man;
>
> also called *irony of fate*
>
> - Example:    *Crane uses the theme of cosmic irony*.

[[Dictionary.com; link disappeared; referenced in Wikipedia blog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AAlbinism_in_popular_culture/Archive_1#Irony)]

My sentence would be: "Consequently, this demonstrates how fate victimizes Oedipus and hints the idea of cosmic irony" then followed by a quote/paraphrase of the definition. Should I use this term or not? Would there be a better way to phrase my argument?

Comment: [Cosmic irony suggests that some unknown force brings about dire and dreadful events.](http://www2.uncp.edu/home/canada/work/allam/general/glossary.htm). [It seems that God or fate is manipulating events so as to inspire false hopes, which are inevitably dashed.](http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~jlynch/Terms/irony.html). [In cosmic irony or the irony of fate, misfortune is the result of fate, chance, or God](http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/english/melani/lit_term.html). It seems like not all literary terms get their own entry in the dictionary. Write with confidence. :^)

Comment: You want to use a term ... is like saying "I want to eat with chopsticks, please tell me what to eat."

Comment: You normally don't "hint irony" (or hint anything else), you "hint at irony" - see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hint)

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony) would be considered authoritative enough by many.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, who are you and what did you do with Mr. Ashworth? I'm tempted to call the authorities…

Comment: @HippoSawrUs There has been a comparison of Wikipedia with Britannica as regards accuracy; it resulted in a tie, if I remember correctly. New entries in Wiktionary will not have been subjected to the same level of editorial scrutiny. // The article referred to in Wikipedia agrees with those from other sources, from respectable-looking writers and writing advisors. It's how I use the term, fwiw.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's a thing. Google "cosmic irony" in quotes and you will get various definitions and explanations of it -- wikipedia, urban dictionary, various literature sites. Google actually shows me "cosmic irony in oedipus the king" as one of the "Searches related to 'cosmic irony'".